# How do I remove certain values of Info map in PDF using iText

Tags: java, itext

It's easy to get such information as title, author etc. of a PDF file using `iText`:

```
Map<String, String> info = pdfReader.getInfo();
```

But how do I remove and modify certain keys/values from that map?

For instance, `info.remove("Title")` doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using the `setMoreInfo()` method on a `PdfStamper` instance. This method loops over the entries of the `Map` you provide, and changes the existing metadata based on the keys stored in the `Map`. If you remove a key, nothing happens (which is what you noticed).

The trick to remove an entry, is to set that entry to `null`:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
Map<String, String> info = reader.getInfo();
info.put("Title", null);
stamper.setMoreInfo(info);
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

You don't even need to retrieve the original metadata from the `PdfReader`; you can just create a `new HashMap<String, String>()` and add a `null` entry for `"Title"`; that will have the same effect:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
Map<String, String> info = new HashMap<String, String>();
info.put("Title", null);
stamper.setMoreInfo(info);
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

As you will see, using an empty `Map` to start with won't remove any metadata entries (*unless* you add a entry with value `null` of course).